# How to use VrPanoramaView to load the photos which token by Cardboard Camera?

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I use the sample of cardboard SDK, which is implemented by VrPanoramaView, then replace the asset as [the sample photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erMIX.jpg) of Cardboard Camera, in consequence, [the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hHJ.jpg) stretched vertically.

However, the only thing I can do is setting VrPanoramaView.Options when calling loadImageFromBitmap, but it can not achieve what I want via existing APIs.

I want to know:

1. If there is a way to implement the photo viewer of Cardboard
   Camera using Cardboard SDK?
2. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no support for Cardboard Camera image on VrPanoramaView, but we hope to add this soon!

Currently VrPanoramaView assumes the incoming images occupy the full 360x 180 (horizontal x vertical) sphere. Your typical Cardboard Camera image is less than that, especially vertically.

One work-around you could try is adding black borders to your image (programmatically or offline using an image editor) so that overall it occupies the full 360x180 sphere.

Comment: I've tried this approach. It works, but not perfect. Thank you anyway.